# Material-UI Select component with many menu items is slow - Alternative solutions

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, react-window

I am trying to make a select element for cities with material-UI. The problem is that I need to have the same design as the Textfields I have above that element. I used the following

```
<FormControl variant='outlined' className={classes.city}>
<InputLabel>City</InputLabel>
 <Select
  label='City'
  value={city}
  onChange={(event) => setCity(event.target.value)}
 >
   {cities.map((storeCity, key) => <MenuItem key={key} value={storeCity.id}>{storeCity.name}</MenuItem>)}
 </Select>
</FormControl>
```

[Before clicking the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssntI.png)

This gives me the perfect visual output and generally works well. The only problem is that it is slow as the cities array contains more than 200 cities. What should I do to have the same visual effect with faster rendering?

Comment: try the autocomplete component 
https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/